# MySQL taking from one table into another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, multiple-tables

Hi I wonder if anyone can help, I'm very new to MySQL and struggling to get it to do what I want it to, i have read a few different post and websites with no luck.
Short and simple, there is something wrong with my query.

```
    $a = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['cardInputOne']);
            $b = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['cardInputTwo']);
            $c = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['cardInputThree']);
            $d = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['cardInputFour']);

            $incomingCardNumber = "{$a}{$b}{$c}{$d}";
            $safeIncomingCard = $mysqli->real_escape_string($incomingCardNumber);
            $fundingUser = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);

            $fundingQuery = "SELECT f.cardValue f.cardNumber FROM funding f 
WHERE f.cardNumber = '{$safeIncomingCard}' 
AND s.email, s.accountBalance FROM shopUser s 
WHERE s.email = '{$fundingUser}'" . 
"UPDATE s.accountBalance = s.accountBalance + f.cardValue";
```

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want the query to do from your question.  However, I suggest reading up on `join` as a starting point.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: you cannot have more than one statement in the same query()` call. and even if you could, yours would be a syntax error, since you're missing a `;` between the two statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to update a table based on data from another table, then it's update you need to use:

```
update shopUser, funding
set shopUser.accountBalance = shopUser.accountBalance + funding.cardValue
where shopUser.email='...' and funding.cardNumber='...'
```

The php variables will replace the ...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the opener wants to update a table with data from another one.
A general way to do that might be:

```
UPDATE
  table1 AS target,
  (SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2) AS source
SET
  target.column3 = source.column1
WHERE
  target.column4 = source.column2
```

where you would have to choose the right source/target columns of course.

Comment: There is no need to reference the 2nd table in a subquery.